# Binding an ArrayList containing DataRow objects to DataGridView.DataSource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, arraylist, datagridview

I'm trying to bind Items from an `ArrayList` called `duplicates` to `DataGridView`. However It is not showing data from `ArrayList` `ItemArray` which is what I want but instead showing metadata.

`duplicates` is type `ArrayList`:

```
duplicates = compare.FindDuplicates(existingLeadFilePath, newLeadFilePath);
gridViewMain.DataSource = duplicates;
```

The Results

[image: Results I get]

[image: Results I require To be displayed]

Comment: Don't post images. Not everyone can see them, and it makes it harder for us to help you... meaning you're less likely to get a good answer. Convert those images into text blocks.

Comment: Also... posting the FindDuplicates() method would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to show an `ArrayList` containing some `DataRow` objects and the `DataGridView` is showing properties of `DataRow`. It's expected.

But propbably you have noticed that when you show a `DataTable` in `DataGridView`, the control shows the columns rather than properties.

**Why? What's the difference between showing a `DataTable` and showing a list of `DataRow` objects?**

The difference is here, `DataGridView` shows `DefaultView` property of the `DataTable` which is of type of `DataView` which implements [`ITypedList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.itypedlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). So it shows just what is returned by [`GetItemProperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.itypedlist.getitemproperties(v=vs.110).aspx) which in fact is asked from `DataTable` and it's a list of table columns.

**How can I show a list of `DataRow` object in `DataGridView`?**

Just add them to a table having the same schema of the origibal table. For examle:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var originalTable = new DataTable();
    originalTable.Columns.Add("C1");
    originalTable.Columns.Add("C2");

    //Original data
    originalTable.Rows.Add("A", "B");
    originalTable.Rows.Add("X", "Y");
    originalTable.Rows.Add("A", "B");
    originalTable.Rows.Add("X", "Y");

    //An ArrayList containing duplicate DataRow objects
    var duplicates = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
    duplicates.Add(originalTable.Rows[2]);
    duplicates.Add(originalTable.Rows[3]);

    //Create a Table having the same schema of the original table
    var duplicatesTable = originalTable.Clone();

    //Add copy of duplicates to the duplicate table
    foreach (DataRow item in duplicates)
    {
        duplicatesTable.Rows.Add(item.ItemArray);
    }
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = duplicates;
}
```

**Note**

You don't need to use `ArrayList` when working with `DataTable`. You have different options like creating an empty DataTable with the same schema using `Clone` method of DataTable, creating a copy of data and schema using `Copy` method, perform some searches using `AsDataView` and `AsEnumerable` and `AsEnumerable().CopyToDataTable()` and so on.

Comment: I totally got it and had been working on it fixing bugs and it works now. Sorry for the late response and Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you want to bind these numbers to the datagridview. What you are doing is binding an array list with some objects that has this array you want as a member, and that's what the datagridview displays.

Try to not use an array with 5 items but a class with 5 members and then use a list of these objects as your data source.

Extended tutorial can be found here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/binding-an-arraylist-with-datagrid-control/

Please excuse my bad English, I'm writing from my mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

This problem goes away if you change the `FindDuplicates()` method to instead return a strongly-typed `List<T>` with a real type in there. Then the DataGridView has actual properties it can look into to know what columns to create.

ArrayLists are dead. You should pretty much never user them in new code. Even if you legitimately can't find a real type to use with a `List<T>`, `List<Object>` is still a better choice over `ArrayList`, as it communicates to the maintainer that the base Object type is really what you want, and it sets you up for easier change if you're ever able to get a stronger type (like an interface) in the future.